# How to create key or append an element to key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an empty dictionary. Name: `dict_x`
It is to have keys of which values are lists.

From a separate iteration, I obtain a key (ex: `key_123`), and an item (a tuple) to place in the list of `dict_x`'s value `key_123`.

If this key already exists, I want to append this item.
If this key does not exist, I want to create it with an empty list and then append to it or just create it with a tuple in it.

In future when again this key comes up, since it exists, I want the value to be appended again.

My code consists of this:

> Get key and value.
>
> See if **NOT** key exists in `dict_x`.
>
> and if not create it: `dict_x[key] == []`
>
> Afterwards: `dict_x[key].append(value)`

Is this the way to do it? Shall I try to use `try/except` blocks?

Answer (score 393, accepted):

Use [`dict.setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)
```

**help(dict.setdefault)**:

```
    setdefault(...)
        D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
```

Comment: I used to do this by `dict_x[key] = [some_value] if not dict_x.has_key(key) else dict_x[key] + [some_value]` but this answer suggests a far better way. In fact it gets `set()` as an argument and allows you to use `add()` method...

Comment: if i do `help(dict.setdefault)` in my python console (v3.9.13) i get a less informative docstring than the one you shared. how come?

Answer (score 102):

Here are the various ways to do this so you can compare how it looks and choose what you like.  I've ordered them in a way that I think is most *"pythonic"*, and commented the pros and cons that might not be obvious at first glance:

**Using `collections.defaultdict`:**

```
import collections
dict_x = collections.defaultdict(list)

...

dict_x[key].append(value)
```

Pros: Probably best performance.  Cons: Not available in Python 2.4.x.

**Using `dict().setdefault()`:**

```
dict_x = {}

...

dict_x.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

Cons: Inefficient creation of unused `list()`s.

**Using `try ... except`:**

```
dict_x = {}

...

try:
    values = dict_x[key]
except KeyError:
    values = dict_x[key] = []
values.append(value)
```

Or:

```
try:
    dict_x[key].append(value)
except KeyError:
    dict_x[key] = [value]
```

Comment: Hello, why do you think .setdefault creates unnecessary dictionaries?

Comment: I don't think `.setdefault()` creates unnecessary dictionaries.  I think *I'm* creating unnecessary `list`s (i.e. `[]`) in the second argument of `.setdefault()` that's never used if `key` already exists.  I could use `dict.setdefault()` (for the benefit of efficient key hashing), and use a variable to reuse unused `list`s but that adds a few more lines of code.

Comment: IIRC, in Python an empty list in an equality is considered a constant at the bytecode level, but this needs some confirmation by a bytecode guru (or just use the disas module).

Comment: Using `.setdefault` creates a regular `dict` where absent key look-up will result in a `KeyError` while `collections.defaultdict(list)` creates a `dict` where absent key lookups will insert an empty `list`-- i think you should choose based on which behaviour you want

Comment: I tried something similar to collections.defaultdict in my own code and it had unexpected side effects. For example consider the following IDLE exchange:
>>> list_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> len(list_dict)
0
>>> len(list_dict[0])
0
>>> len(list_dict)
1
It appears that when Python invokes the default value it adds the key to the dictionary without you actively setting it, which is going to create a lot of empty lists if the default is used much. I'm going to roll my own wrapper functions for the dictionary, inefficient but hopefully more predictable.

Answer (score 39):

You can use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d['key'].append('mykey')
```

This is slightly more efficient than `setdefault` since you don't end up creating new lists that you don't end up using. Every call to `setdefault` is going to create a new list, even if the item already exists in the dictionary.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in `collections`.

An example from doc:

```
s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 13):

```
dictionary['key'] = dictionary.get('key', []) + list_to_append
```

Comment: You should explain the (very minor) advantage that this has in the presence of certain exceptions; as just code, it's not clear why the additional answer is needed.

Comment: Hi, just an alternative without additional imports. This can clearly be done with an if statement. I am just suggesting an alternative using the power of .get() instead of using dict[].

Comment: The top two answers mention two different ways with no imports (albeit not `dict.get`).

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

The more lengthy and expressive approach seems also to be more performant.

```py
if key in dest:
    dest[key].append(value)
else:
    dest[key] = [value]
```

**Longer answer**

I wrote some python lines to check whether the proposed approach is actually the best in term of performance.

```py
d1 = {}
d2 = {}

def add1(key, value, dest):
        dest.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
            
def add2(key, value, dest):
    if key in dest:
        dest[key].append(value)
    else:
        dest[key] = [value]
```

This results in

```
%timeit add1('a', 1.1, d1)
  96.2 ns ± 0.0972 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit add2('a', 1.1, d2)
  89.1 ns ± 0.111 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

Tested on my python setup (`3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0]`) executing Jupyter NB.

It's worth it to point out that opting for the lengthier and more expressive approach can also impact positively on performance in this case.