# Merge Series of a pandas column (which is a Series itself) in groups

Tags: list, pandas, merge, group-by, series

I have a pandas data frame in which one of the columns is a Series itself. Eg:

```
df.head()

Col1    Col2  
1       ["name1","name2","name3"]  
1       ["name3","name2","name4"]  
2       ["name1","name2","name3"] 
2       ["name1","name5","name6"]
```

I need to concatenate the Col2 in groups of Col1. I want something like

```
Col1    Col2  
1       ["name1","name2","name3","name4"]  
2       ["name1","name2","name3","name5","name6"]
```

I tries using a groupby as

```
.agg({"Col2":lambda x: pd.Series.append(x)})
```

But this throws error saying two parameters are required. I also tried using sum in the agg function. That fails with error does not reduce.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` custom function, where first flatten nested lists by `chain` (fastest [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/2901002)), then remove duplicates by `set`, convert to `list` and last sort:

```
import pandas as pd
from  itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1,1,2,2],
                   'Col2':[["name1","name2","name3"],
                           ["name3","name2","name4"],
                           ["name1","name2","name3"],
                           ["name1","name5","name6"]]})

print (df)
   Col1                   Col2
0     1  [name1, name2, name3]
1     1  [name3, name2, name4]
2     2  [name1, name2, name3]
3     2  [name1, name5, name6]
```

```
print (df.groupby('Col1')['Col2']
         .apply(lambda x: sorted(list(set(list(chain.from_iterable(x))))))
         .reset_index())
   Col1                                 Col2
0     1         [name1, name2, name3, name4]
1     2  [name1, name2, name3, name5, name6]
```

Solution can be more simplier, only `chain`, `set` and `sorted` is necessary:

```
print (df.groupby('Col1')['Col2']
         .apply(lambda x: sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(x))))
         .reset_index())

   Col1                                 Col2
0     1         [name1, name2, name3, name4]
1     2  [name1, name2, name3, name5, name6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you wouldn't be able to use `.aggby{}` on categorical data like this. Anyway, here's my stab at the problem, using the help up of numpy. (commented for clarity)

```
import numpy as np

# Set group by ("Col1") unique values
groupby = df["Col1"].unique()

# Create empty dict to store values on each iteration
d = {}

for i,val in enumerate(groupby):

    # Set "Col1" key, to the unique value (e.g., 1)
    d.setdefault("Col1",[]).append(val)

    # Create empty list to store values from "Col2"
    col2_unis=[]

    # Create sub-DataFrame for each unique groupby value
    sdf = df.loc[df["Col1"]==val]

    # Loop through the 2D-array/Series "Col2" and append each 
    # value to col_unis (using list comprehension)
    col2_unis.append([[j for j in array] for i,array in enumerate(sdf["Col2"].values)])

    # Set "Col2" key, to be unique values of col2_unis
    d.setdefault("Col2",[]).append(np.unique(col2_unis))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(new_df)
```

A more condensed version would look like:

```
d = {}
for i,val in enumerate(df["Col1"].unique()):
    d.setdefault("Col1",[]).append(val)
    sdf = df.loc[df["Col1"]==val]
    d.setdefault("Col2",[]).append(np.unique([[j for j in array] for i,array in enumerate(df.loc[df["Col1"]==val, "Col2"].values)]))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(new_df)
```

Learn more about Python's `.setdefault()` function for dictionaries, by checking out [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905999/python-dict-how-to-create-key-or-append-an-element-to-key).