# How can we seperate the url's with their status code in python?

Tags: python

I am making a small project. The project is in the python and I am now stuck in a problem and i.e.

I have a list of URLs with their response code like 200, 300, 400, 403.

Okay let's make it more clear

```
http://aa.domain.com 200
http://bb.domain.com 302
http://cc.domain.com 400
http://dd.domain.com 403
http://ee.domain.com 403
```

Now what I exactly want is I want to seperate the URLs with their status code.

**Like a "Making a Seperate list of 400 and 403 URLs".**

**How can I do it with python? As a newbie, I can't. Could You?**

EDIT:- I have tried this

```
        try:
         req = requests.get(xxx) #xxx is a list of subdomains
         responsecode = xxx , req.status_code, "\n"

         print responsecode

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:   
            print "Not full fill request"
```

I only can print the response code. And successfully print the response code as like I said above

Comment: can you show expected output? also, what have you tried so far

Comment: Well if you are a newbie let us know what you tried before asking for help.

Comment: Do you want to make separate lists for URLs with different responses? Why not maintain a dictionary which looks as follows: `{ 400: [list,of,url], 200: [another,list,..], etc.. }`

Comment: You should do what @SudheeshSinganamalla suggested. And use this to do that: [Python dict how to create key or append an element to key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905999/python-dict-how-to-create-key-or-append-an-element-to-key).

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function to split the request in to two (request code & URL) & inserted into dictionary till the size of request list .

I am also attach the screenshot of the output .

```
dictionary = {}
request = ["http://aa.domain.com 200", "http://bb.domain.com 302", "http://cc.domain.com 400", "http://dd.domain.com 403", "http://ee.domain.com 403"]
for i in range(0, len(request)) :
  word = request[i].split(" ")[1];
  dictionary[word] = request[i].split(" ")[0];


print(dictionary)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Well for the query you asked we can solve it by using dictionary in python for desired output. Checkout the code snippet below :

```
dict = {}
req = ["http://aa.domain.com 200", "http://bb.domain.com 302", "http://cc.domain.com 400", "http://dd.domain.com 403", "http://ee.domain.com 403"]
for i in range(0, len(req)) :
    term = req[i].split(" ")
    while True :
        if term[1] not in dict.keys():
            dict.setdefault(term[1], [])
            dict[term[1]].append(term[0])
            break
        else :
            dict[term[1]].append(term[0])
            break
print(dict)
```

It gives the desired output as :

```
{'200': ['http://aa.domain.com'], '400': ['http://cc.domain.com'], '403': ['http://dd.domain.com', 'http://ee.domain.com'], '302': ['http://bb.domain.com']}
```

Let me know if you are unable to understand it.

Comment: `while True: ... if: break ... else: break`. What's the point of this?

Comment: Also, you can directly use `dict.setdefault(code, []).append(url)`

Comment: @Keyur : Well surely we are here to solve problems in more understanding way rather than just solving them. As clearly I wrote it in simple manner for my and others better understanding.