# Python dict how to create key or update key in one line?

Tags: python, dictionary

My question is similar to
[Python dict how to create key or append an element to key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905999/python-dict-how-to-create-key-or-append-an-element-to-key)

I want to create the following dictionary of dictionaries:

```
my_dict = {
 "name1" : { "id1" : "pin1", "id2" : "pin2" },
 "name2" : { "id3" : "pin3", "id4" : "pin4" }
}
```

I currently accomplish this using the following:

```
if name in my_dict:
    my_dict[name].update({ id : pin }
else:
    my_dict[name] = { id : pin }
```

Is there a way to do this using dict.setdefault() ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this using dict.setdefault() ?

Of course! There's nothing magic about `setdefault`; it just returns `my_dict[name]` if it exists, or sets `my_dict[name] = default` and returns `default` if not.

Either way, what it returns is the (potentially new) dict in `my_dict[name]`, so all you have to do is update it:

```
my_dict.setdefault(name, {})[id] = pin
```

Or, if you really like using `update` instead of just `[] =`:

```
my_dict.setdefault(name, {}).update({id: pin})
```

For example:

```
>>> my_dict.setdefault('name1', {})['id10']= 'pin10'
>>> my_dict.setdefault('name3', {})['id20']= 'pin20'
{'name1': {'id1': 'pin1', 'id10': 'pin10', 'id2': 'pin2'},
 'name2': {'id3': 'pin3', 'id4': 'pin4'},
 'name3': {'id20': 'pin20'}}
```

---

More generally, you could obviously rewrite your existing code to this:

```
if name not in my_dict:
    my_dict[name] = {}
my_dict[name].update({ id : pin }
```

Whenever you can do that, you can use `setdefault`. (But notice that we're *calling a mutating method* or *assigning to a key/index/member* of `my_dict[name]` here, not just assigning a new value to `my_dict[name]`. That's the key to it being useful.)

---

Of course almost any time you can use `setdefault`, you can also [use `defaultdict` (as demonstrated in CoryKramer's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50163669/908494) (and vice-versa). If you want defaulting behavior *all the time*, use `defaultdict`. Only use `setdefault` if you want defaulting behavior *just this once* (e.g., you want defaulting while building the dict up, but you want `KeyError`s later when using it).

Comment: above code snippet should say if name not in my_dict:

Comment: @crusarovid Thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(dict)
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {})
>>> my_dict['name1'].update({'id1': 'pin1'})
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'name1': {'id1': 'pin1'}})
```

Then you don't need the `if` statement, you can directly call `update`, and if no `dict` yet exists for that `name` a new one will be created before calling `update`