# Append value to list of dictionary key without an empty list issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

## [PYTHON 3.7 - Append to list for dictionary key]

How do I append to a list for a dictionary key when the keys are being created within the `for loop`?

---

#### Background:

I am parsing a `.xml` file to a nested `OrderedDict` and I recursively flatten out the `OrderedDict` into a `list` that has three elements: `[level_depth, key, value]`.

*This is my recursive function:*

```
def iterdict(d, lvl, ARR):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            lvl += 1
            iterdict(v, lvl, ARR)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                if isinstance(i, dict):
                    lvl += 1
                    iterdict(i, lvl, ARR)
        else:
            print(lvl, k, v)
            ARR.append([lvl, k, v])
    return ARR
```

This is my attempt to create a dict where all the `level_depth` values are grouped as a single key:

```
A = iterdict(my_dict, 0, [])

A_dict = {}
for i in A:
    A_dict[str(i[0])].append(i[:-1])
```

*Error:*

`A_dict[str(i[0])].append([i[:-1]])
KeyError: '1'`

This is a sample output of the **`A`** list:

```
[...,  [17, '@Name', 'ExternalVisible'], [17, '@SystemDefined', 'true'], [17, '#text', 'false'], 
[18, '@Name', 'ExternalWritable'], [18, '@SystemDefined', 'true'], [18, '#text', 'false'], 
[19, '@Informative', 'true'], [19, '@Name', 'UserVisible'], ...]
```

---

#### Query Details

So I understand that the key error comes up because there is no list at that key to append to.
How can I create a key with a new list and then append to it?

Example of my required result using the `sample output`:

```
A_dict = {..., '17': [['@Name', 'ExternalVisible'], ['@SystemDefined', 'true'], ['#text', 'false']]...}
```

Any advice on best practice will be appreciated too, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python dict how to create key or append an element to key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905999/python-dict-how-to-create-key-or-append-an-element-to-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create a key with a new list and then append to it?

you can use [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
A_dict = {}
for i in A:
    A_dict.setdefault(str(i[0]), []).append(i[:-1])
```

or you can use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
 import collections
 A_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```